# Repeat analysis for several datasets in R

Tags: r, function

How can I repeat this code for each subject (xxx), so that the results are added to the data.frame (centralities)?

```
fullDataDetrend_xxx <- subset(fullDataDetrend, subjno == xxx, select=c(subjno,depressed,sad,tired,interest,happy,neg_thoughts,concentration_probl,ruminating,activity,datevar,timestamp,dayno,beepno))

  model_xxx <- var1( 
    fullDataDetrend_xxx)

model_xxx_omega <- getmatrix(model_xxx, "omega_zeta")
centrality_model_xxx_omega <- centrality(model_xxx_omega )

centralities[nrow(centralities) + 1,] <- c("xxx",centrality_model_xxx_omega$InExpectedInfluence)
```

Comment: You can `sp <- split(fullDataDetrend, fullDataDetrend$subjno)` then `lapply` a function with you code to each split list member. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(fullDataDetrend)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(fullDataDetrend, 20))`.

Comment: Also, please explicitly load the libraries you use. `var1`, `centrality` and `getmatrix` are not base R functions, in what packages can they be found? Start your code example with `library()` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did as suggested:

```
fullDataDetrend_split <- split(fulldataDetrend, fulldataDetrend$subjno)
```

then, to estimate network, pull centrality estimates, and write to centralities in global environment:

```
analyze_one <- function(dataframe){
  network_model <- var1( 
    dataframe,
    vars = useVars,
    contemporaneous = "ggm",
    dayvar = "dayno",
    beepvar = "beepno",
    estimator = "FIML",
    verbose = TRUE,
    omega_zeta = "full")
    model_omega <- getmatrix(network_model, "omega_zeta")
    centrality_omega<- centrality(model_omega)
    model_beta <- getmatrix(network_model, "beta")
    centrality_beta<- centrality(model_beta)
    subjno <- as.list(dataframe[1,2])
    centralities[nrow(centralities) + 1,] <- c(subjno,centrality_omega$InExpectedInfluence,centrality_beta$InExpectedInfluence,centrality_beta$OutExpectedInfluence)
    assign('centralities',centralities, envir=.GlobalEnv)
    }
```

then rerun the code with lapply for all dataframes (with ignoring errors):

```
lapply_with_error <- function(X,FUN,...){    
  lapply(X, function(x, ...) tryCatch(FUN(x, ...),
                                      error=function(e) NULL))
}
lapply_with_error(fullDataDetrend_split, FUN = analyze_one)
```